# How do you set and get values with Chrome.Storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do a very simple setting and retrieving with a Google Chrome extension using chrome.storage.local

I have the part to set it:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"myValue": "All the data I need"});
```

I just don't understand how to retrieve it.

```
alert(chrome.storage.local.get("myValue"));
```

I've read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage the part that's confusing me is why there is supposed to be a function as part of storage.local.get

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab5_data

Comment: just a quick tip, and it's not necessarily a good one, but if you haven't worked with storage before, use sessionstorage/localstorage first for a while. (I made a few stupid mistakes in my first chrome extension due to lack of experience in working with storage myself)

Answer (score 5):

To add to source.rar's correct, but terse answer:

Your problem starts with misunderstanding how `set` works, too. Both `set` and `get` are asynchronous, so the execution would look like this:

```
// 1. Suppose the stored value for A is "a"
chrome.storage.local.set({A:"b"});
// 2. The stored value for A is still "a"
```

This happens because `set` doesn't do anything immediately, and just adds the actual setting of the value into the execution queue for JavaScript.

You can add a callback for `set`, too. It get pushed to the queue after the setting operation:

```
// 1. Suppose the stored value for A is "a"
chrome.storage.local.set({A:"b"}, function(){
  // 3. This will execute after the outer function finishes
  //    and setting is done; the value for A is "b"
});
// 2. The stored value for A is still "a"
```

Now, how would this work?

```
// 1. Suppose the stored value for A is "a"
chrome.storage.local.set({A:"b"}, function(){
  // 3. This will execute after the outer function finishes
  //    and setting is done; the value for A is "b"
});
// 2. The stored value for A is still "a"
chrome.storage.local.get("A", function(data){
   // ??
});
// ??
```

The outer function that calls `set` and `get` just adds stuff to the queue and finishes; then the first two items added to the queue, `set` and its callback, and the the other two, `get` and its callback:

```
// 1. Suppose the stored value for A is "a"
chrome.storage.local.set({A:"b"}, function(){
  // 4. This will execute after the outer function finishes
  //    and setting is done; the value for A is "b"
});
// 2. The stored value for A is still "a"
chrome.storage.local.get("A", function(data){
  // 5. This will execute after the outer function finishes
  //    and everything else is done;
  //    the value for A is "b" and data.A is "b"
});
// 3. The stored value for A is still "a"
```

---

So, often you will have to chain execution using callbacks, i.e.

```
// part 1
chrome.storage.local.get("A", function(data){
  //part 2
  chrome.storage.local.get("B", function(data){
    // part 3
  }
}
```

*Sometimes* you can simplify the above by asking for both at the same time:

```
// part 1
chrome.storage.local.get(["A", "B"], function(data){
  //part 2
  //part 3
}
```

It is possible to simplify the whole thing by writing your own synchronous cache for `chrome.storage`; but it's also not always suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. To retrieve it you need to implement the callback part of the get() as Chrome returns the data to you via an argument to that function. So in your case you would need something like,

```
chrome.storage.local.get("myValue", function(obj) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
}):
```

Due to the event driven and single-threaded nature of JavaScript code, most chrome API's (as well as most JavaScript code) use this asynchronous construct to "return" values , and is different from the more traditional "function returns a value approach".

With this approach when you invoke an API function you also pass it another function (the callback function) that contains the code you want executed when the API function completes its processing (which in my code above is the function with the alert()). The API function on completion then invokes the callback function with the results of its operation.

Comment: Your response, along with Xan's, has helped me to understand why it's not functioning.
Right now I'm trying to get this to work just as an example:
`chrome.storage.local.set("myValue", "golfish");

        chrome.storage.local.get("myValue", function(obj) {
            alert(obj);
        });`
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you so much for your patience. I am new at coding and right now I'm learning by building my own, fairly simple, Chrome extension.

Comment: The chrome.storage.*.set() function takes an object as it's first argument. so you need to pass it an object like so `chrome.storage.local.set({"myValue":"golfish"}, function() {console.log("set callback on completion");});`